# Access dynamic / generic classes' properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using this (complexity super reduced) base model in Typescript:

```
export class ModelBase<T> {
    constructor(base: T) {
        Object.assign(this, base);
    }
}
```

If I now try to use it as follows:

```
interface Model {
    prop: string;
}

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        let instance = new ModelBase<Model>({ prop: 'test' });
        instance.prop = 'x';
    }
}
```

Typescript tells me there is no property `prop` in my instance. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[microsoft/TypeScript#2225](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225), originally filed in 2015, requests similar cases where a class or interface extends a generic type. The discussion was closed, though some commenters seem to maintain at the end that the type intersection recommendations do not meet their needs.

As such, one way to do this is to make a static factory method that returns a type intersection of `ModelBase<T> & T`:

```
export class ModelBase<T> {
    static wrap<T>(base: T) {
        return new ModelBase<T>(base) as ModelBase<T> & T;
    }

    constructor(base: T) {
        Object.assign(this, base);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkIBNhIBC6wAPACoB8cA3gFByNxowowCWCcA7lCmBUoAKAEYkAXHHIBKWgyYKowGAFcoAOzjrg3bHgLE0ZKqJKz0e-ERKC4AMikBueYwC+dF4gjqWUFQhhoUyNJGTkFBQB5EQArYACAOnQ0dgBzdSEYAAt2NAAaODEjaWcFd3c6dnUYYCgAMxQEYEsCcKYwKAgwSV8q1OcK5GTsAE8AYVQMNsYEb19-QKghWXoIpiRlOCqWFHUmuABeFusjBN5+IRo4Dq7JAHIalju4VxLPBW3WPeAEm7BDuB3EB3UpMcp0IA)

Naturally, the function could easily be top-level or adjacent to the class rather than within it Java-style. Also, bear in mind that like with everything TypeScript you'll have an imprecise reflection of which properties are [enumerable own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (see [#9726](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726)), which might be a signficantly narrower set than what you and TypeScript would expect to be available on `ModelBase<Foo>`. Conversely, you may copy more at runtime than TS can expect at compile-time, and ModelBase instances may have their methods and fields hidden if you have name collisions between ModelBase and whichever T types you're copying: TypeScript will only show you the inferred compile-time interactions rather than any unexpected enumerable runtime properties that `Object.assign` will copy for you.

Alternatives that don't work:

- [`ModelBase<T> extends T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkIBNhIBC6wAPACoB8coMwAdrpuXAN4BQcXiE9aMUAK4IY0ABQAjEgC445AJRtO3FQHkJAK2AiAdOjQBLAOb0xMABYG0AGjhS0weQG5lXAL7sP7A-TpQAZigIwNh4BEoqYFAQYLL8UD5GLl7I+tgAngDCqBgR3Ai88cKiUGKKHCoqSMDwPvwo9MFwALxw9MAA7qH4RCSkOD2UYqxwUTGyAOR0-BNwbs6ulXUwDcE6Y2AtcBMgEy4qHh5AA), see [#4890](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4890) which led to mixins below
- [`ModelBase<T> implements T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkIBNhIBC6wAPACoB8cAlgLZhLB3AB2Mm5cA3gFBwDEEVmhhQArghjQAFACMSALjjkAlD36CtAeTkArYFIB06NDQDmrGTAAWNNABo4CtMFUBuTQIC+vX7xp2YCgAMxQEYGw8Ag0tMCgIMGVRKEDzT39kU2wATwBhVAxYwQRhFMlpKBl1Pi0tJnhA0RRWCLgAXjhWYAB3KPwiElIcAcoZbjh4xOUAchhgURm4bw8vOqaYFoijKbAOuBmQGc8tX18gA), see [#2225](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225) linked above
- [constructor returns `ModelBase<T> & T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkIBNhIBC6wAPACoB8cA3gFByOIQB2aMUArgjNABQAjEgC445AJSic+IiQrUAZGNoMmagPICAVsB4A6dGgCWAcxZ8YACyNoANHCFpg4gNyrGAXzpe6RljGAoADMUBGBsPAIVNTAoCDBRdig-EzcfZENsAE8AYVQMaKYEViTuXig+cUK1RiRgeD92FBYwuABeOBZgAHcImWInUmkCSj4aOFj40QByAPZpuA9XdxrGmGawvUmwdrhpkGm3NS8vIA), see [#27594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594)
- [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), see [#13743](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743): Mixins necessarily accept constructor functions, not instances with interface types

Comment: I've **never** ever felt so good spending my reputation! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

On way is that you add parameter in type `T` to `ModelBase` like this:

```
export class ModelBase<T> {
    param!:T;
    constructor(base: T) {
        Object.assign(this.param, base);
    }
}


interface Model {
    prop: string;
}

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        let instance = new ModelBase<Model>({ prop: 'test' });
        instance.param.prop = "x";
    }
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkIBNhIBC6wAPACoB8cA3gLABQAkGClCgLYCEAXOQNyM4wxBAB2aGFACuCGNAAUAIxI845AJS0hI3QHklAK2ByAdOjQBLAOZiFMABaW0p1uw4AaOCrTANghl0AX0YQhkZGSzEYYCgAMxQEYGw8Am1AkTAoCDA1SSgo6wCwxmQLbABPAGFUDHTdBHF82XkoBS16DN1hJGB4KMkUMSS4AF44MWAAdxT8IhJSHDnKBRo4LJy1AHIYyS24IP9GJiYBmCGk1zZOV2ywMbgAIhBHgODQoA)

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation! But for castings and many other things (like I've said, pretty simplified) I need the instance to be of type `T`.

Comment: @tris you can't access to dynamic properties as strongly typed with intelligence. The only way is using `[]`.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way? So I'll use a workaround. Thought it would / could be possible in TS to generically implement an interface.

Comment: @tris As far as I know there is no way. So you can use my way or any other workaround you find