# Can I have a class implement an interface without re-typing out all the types?

Tags: typescript

Consider as case where we get some raw data from an API or whatnot that we expect to have a shape of `ICustomer`, but then we want to extend that functionality, with member functions and perhaps additional variables as part of a `Customer` class.

```
interface ICustomer {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

class Customer implements ICustomer {
  ...
}
```

From this, the compiler knows that `Customer` will have (at least) `name` and `address`. Is there a way to have these be defined without my explicitly typing them out? Basically what I'd like to do is

```
class Customer implements ICustomer {
    constructor(data: ICustomer) {
       Object.assign(this, data)
    }

    someExtraFunctionality() { ... }
}
```

It seems silly that I would have to define each member twice.

Is this doable in some clean way? I imagine I could do some hackery with `as any as Customer`, but it feels there should be a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access dynamic / generic classes' properties in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644375/access-dynamic-generic-classes-properties-in-typescript)

Comment: It is one approach that could be taken to achieve this, but it's also pretty verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no.

---

You could use the class's instance type as an interface:

```
type WithoutFunctions<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? never : K]: T[K]
}

class Customer {
    name: string;
    address: string;

    constructor(data: WithoutFunctions<Customer>) {
       Object.assign(this, data)
    }

    someExtraFunctionality() {}
}

const customer = new Customer({ name: 'a', address: 'b' })
```

Here the constructor takes an object that is only the value properties, no methods, and assigns it to the instance. It requires a cumbersome utility type to strip out the functions though.

---

Similarly, you could use `Pick` to grab just the properties you want from the class type:

```
type ICustomer = Pick<Customer, 'name' | 'address'>

class Customer {
    name: string;
    address: string;

    constructor(data: ICustomer) {
       Object.assign(this, data)
    }

    someExtraFunctionality() {}
}

const customer = new Customer({ name: 'a', address: 'b' })
```

---

And this may give you this error:

```
Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)
```

Which you can solve by adding a `!` to the property in order to say that it may be `undefined` but you should always treat it as a `string`. This makes typescript not care that it doesn't ever look to be initialized.

```
name!: string
```

I wouldn't recommend that though, and this feature is fairly type unsafe and allows bugs to leak in.

---

But really, I think duplicating the properties is your best bet. It may be little verbose, but Typescript will verify you did it correctly, and yell at you if you didn't making this trivial to get right.

```
type ICustomer = {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

class Customer implements ICustomer {
    name: string;
    address: string;
    
    constructor(data: ICustomer) {
       this.name = data.name
       this.address = data.address
    }

    someExtraFunctionality() {}
}

const customer = new Customer({ name: 'a', address: 'b' })
```

It's simple, it's clear, very type safe, and Typescript will light up red if you get the name of type of any of those props wrong.

Comment: Won't both your first 2 options fail unless `strictPropertyInitialization` is set to false? Logically it shouldn't; typescript knows the input type has the required members, and knows they will be assigned, but it complains anyway.

Comment: It will fail, yes, and part of my answer addresses that. But Typescript doesn't think that `Object.assign` is capable of initializing a property. In fact, no function is. The only thing that is capable of that is `this.name = 'something'` or `constructor(public name: string) {}`. I suppose you could call it a limitation of the compiler.

Comment: That's unfortunate; guess it's not too much effort to maintain. I think this (https://pastebin.com/jfg9j9km) will work, and doesn't require the strict property flag, but seems  a little too unwieldy. Having to write out the variable name 4 times when it should be just one feels kinda dirty though. Reminds me too much of Java.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can try to use type instead of interface

```
type CustomerType = {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

class Customer {
    constructor(data: CustomerType) {
       Object.assign(this, data)
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

This can work with all optional attributes

```
data = Object.assign(this, data)
```

I usually assign values this way

```
class Customer implements ICustomer {
    constructor(data: ICustomer = {}) { //assign an empty object as a default value
       for (let key in data) {
         this[key] = data[key];
       }
    }

    function someExtraFunctionality() { ... }
}
```

but again, it only works if all your interface attributes are optional

```
interface ICustomer {
  name?: string;
  address?: string;
}
```

It's not simple like `Object.assign` but it's useful for your case.

Comment: This doesn't work because typescript complains "Customer incorrectly implements ICustomer. Property 'name' is missing...", and the point of my question is basically to avoid duplicating this.

Comment: You want all attributes required? If all of them are required, we need to put them into the constructor explicitly.

Comment: I think this (https://pastebin.com/mDn54SLB) will do it, but it's weird. (looking at it, I think I need a constructor on CustomerClass, but you get the idea). There *should* be a better way...

Comment: @Rollie I just updated my answer by using `type` instead of `interface`. It's working perfectly for me

Comment: This will kinda work, but any user of this code where they have a variable of type `const c: Customer`, if they try to do `console.log(c.name)` it won't work because typescript doesn't know `Customer` has the `name` property.